# AWS CLI in Docker : aws iot-data delete-thing-name .... --shadow-name .... /dev/stdout --no-verify-ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, raspberry-pi, iot

I have completed the **aws configure**, and run the command below in Raspberry Pi local environment. It work well in local environemnt.

1. aws iot-data delete-thing-shadow .... --thing-name .... --shadow-name .... /dev/stdout --no-verify-ssl
2. aws iot-data update-thing-shadow .... --thing-name .... --shadow-name .... /dev/stdout --no-verify-ssl

However, when I run the command in Docker, it shows me some errors like :

1. SSL validation failed for ..... unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
2. [X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4053).

I have referred the following links, but still can't solve the problem

1. https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2686
2. https://www.shellhacks.com/aws-cli-ssl-validation-failed-solved/
3. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1545

Anyone faces the same problem and solve it?

Comment: I found the question is that the awscli version